# Jobs in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I am a professional programmer. But, I am new to Stack Overflow. That's why I don't have much more reputation. But, currently I am in need of a job. Even, my education qualifications isn't good (i.e. I am under-graduated). Although I need job. So, if I apply for a job will they reply/respond?

I heard from friend that *He hasn't heard from anyone that anyone gets jobs from Stack Overflow*. Are those jobs legitimate?

Comment: Reputation on Stack Overflow has nothing to do with getting hired. It has never even gotten me a reply from anyone advertising on Stack Overflow Jobs. However, the jobs *are*  (generally) legitimate.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant, but the "*brother/friend*" is a bit odd. Did you hear this from a friend or a brother? If it's your brother, and you are friends with them, you would simply say "brother".

Comment: Brother from another mother, @cigien?

Comment: @cigien I disagree. That's could be odd or weird from everyone but not for me. Cause, I take everyone as friend. Cause, I believe there's no relative of mine. But, he calls me brother that's why I said that

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable way to look at things. I was only pointing out that it could be confusing to most readers of the question, and that's probably not something you want.

Comment: bro, this explanation is not legit. I've edited that strange text out... and strongly recommend to [edit] the question more - I understand you want to demonstrate something with that "is this sh** legit" stance, but it is not necessary a good fit for a post from a professional programmer.

Comment: *"if I apply for a job will they respond?"* Only one way to find out.

Comment: @adiga What is that?

Comment: By applying for those jobs.

Comment: Note, however, that applying for jobs as an "experiment" is likely to backfire in the long run, reinforcing the tendency of employers *not* to reply to applicants. Please only apply if/when you are genuinely interested. Then, their failure to reply rests solely on them, and you can keep a clear conscience.

Comment: @CodyGray Could you please visit [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404973/delay-jobs-response)

Comment: Why do you want me to visit that? I've already looked at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can attest to the fact that many of these jobs are, in fact, legit; at a minimum, I can attest to the fact that my company's postings here are actual positions that we're hiring for (since I have admin access to the applicant tracking system).

That being said, I may be shooting myself in the foot here, but job boards in general are not the most efficient way of getting a job. My company hires far less than 1% of people who apply that way.

I recall a test job that we posted to a job board in the early days of rolling out the system; it clearly stated in numerous places in bold letters that it was test job and people shouldn't apply. Of course, we still got dozens of applications to it in the short time that it was posted publicly (which we then had to figure out what to do with). My point in telling that story is that job boards frequently attract a large number of variably-qualified candidates (in this case, it was obvious that none of the applicants had even read the job description; they probably just used the job board's "Quick Apply" feature because the job title seemed vaguely related). (Some people, myself included, openly questioned at various points whether job boards were even worth bothering with in the first place).

In terms of getting a job, there was one [study](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/eye-tracking-study-among-recruiters-how-pass-initial-resume-eekman) that suggested that recruiters scan resumes for the contact information, job titles, and education when they're looking at a resume for the first time. That being said, if you're weak in those areas, you may want to try to enhance your resume by getting an internship, attending some kind of additional training program, getting additional education, or getting some kind of certification, otherwise it'll be hard for you to get past the initial resume screen by recruiters regardless of how you apply for jobs.

Also, Stack Overflow reputation will generally not get you a job. I will freely admit to including a link to my Stack Overflow profile on my resume, but I can only recall one case where someone actually looked it up, and I didn't end up getting that particular job.

Comment: Generally, it means it's hard to get a job from Stack Overflow

Comment: I have another question. Suppose, I have got a job. But, I am busy nowadays with lot of troubles. Can I tell them to delay that?

Comment: This is very interesting to read; in particular, the statistic that your company at least hires "far less than 1% of the people who apply" via job boards. That raises the question of how you generally *do* hire people. Where do you find the people? What are the more efficient way(s) of getting hired? Do you need to know someone? Just show up at the door? DDoS your servers?

Comment: @CodyGray Referrals from current employees are the most likely to get hired, oddly enough followed by submissions from agencies (possibly because they pre-screen candidates more and possibly because they can advocate with them with hiring managers).

Comment: There might be some survivorship bias at work here. For public job postings, the company has to do the screening. In contrast, employee referrals and agency submissions are already filtered for quality before they hit the recruitment process. So the rejection rate for public posting will always be (significantly!) higher than for internal/professional postings.